# Using for loop inside return() function to display data in lists

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 lists as follow :

`customer_id = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`customer_name = [John, Michael, Sara, Tony, Angel]`

I need to display above data in table as different rows.
I have written the code as below but its not working.

```
return (    
< div >   
          for(var i=0; i< customer_id.length; i++){    
          < tr>    
               < td>{customer_id[i]}< /td>    
               < td>{customer_name[i]}< /td>    
          < /tr>    
}    
< /div >    
);
```

I would love to know where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code. How come `<tr>` inside `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it as below using `Array.map`. Using `.map` we are here creating an array of table rows. Then `App` component rendering the actual table with those `<tr>` as table body.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function TableRows({ customerIds, customerNames }) {
  return customerIds.map((id, index) => (
    <tr key={id}>
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>{customerNames[index]}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
}

function App() {
  var customerIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var customerNames = ["John", "Michael", "Sara", "Tony", "Angel"];

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <TableRows customerIds={customerIds} customerNames={customerNames} />
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7mkqq7ol70).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `for` loop, you could have an array that you push each `tr` to and then render the array after the loop.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    customer_id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    customer_name: ["John", "Michael", "Sara", "Tony", "Angel"]
  };

  render() {
    const { customer_id, customer_name } = this.state;
    const result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < customer_id.length; i++) {
      result.push(
        <tr key={customer_id[i]}>
          <td>{customer_id[i]}</td>
          <td>{customer_name[i]}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }

    return <div> {result} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring your data as a list of customers, having two separate lists can get messy.

```
var customers = [{Id:1, Name:John}, {Id:2, Name:Michael}, {Id:3, Name:Sara}, {Id:4, Name:Angel}, {Id:5, Name:Tony}]

var result = (
    {customers.map((customer, index) => (
          < tr>    
               < td>{customer.Id}< /td>    
               < td>{customer.Name}< /td>    
          < /tr>   
    ))})

return <div> {result} </div>;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map for more information on the array.map function.